# Camera4Kivy displays Image in -90° position when taking picture in portrait orientation

Tags: python, android, kivy

- kivy: 2.2.1
- kivymd 1.2.0dev0
- camera4kivy 0.3.0
- python3

[image]
I'm using the package Camera4Kivy, but unfortunately, when I take a portrait Image it rotates the image 90° antiClockwise, and when my phone is horizontal, so in landscape mode, the rendering is fine, as the picture in attachment shows it.
I've tried to distinguish when I'am in portrait or landscape with pyjnius, but as I want my app to be strictly in portrait (buildozer.spec orientation = portrait), I could'nt find a way, Do you have any idea how I should do this ?

```
from os import listdir
import time
import os
from kivymd.uix.imagelist import MDSmartTile
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.logger import Logger
from android_permissions import AndroidPermissions
from camera4kivy import Preview
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.cache import Cache
from toast import Toast
from os.path import join
from PIL import Image

if platform == "android":
    from jnius import autoclass
    from android.storage import app_storage_path, primary_external_storage_path
    from android import mActivity, api_version
    Environment = autoclass('android.os.Environment')

def log(msg):
    Logger.info(msg)


KV = '''

<MyMDSmartTile>:
    radius: 24
    box_radius: 0, 0, 24, 24
    box_color: 0, 0, 0, .5
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: "160dp" # à faire varier
    mipmap: False # if True OpenGL mipmapping to be applied to the texture

    MDIconButton:
        icon: "camera"
        on_release: 
            app.root.ids._picture_screen.tile = root
            app.root.ids._picture_screen.picture_name = root.text
            app.root.current = "picture_screen"

    MDLabel:
        text: root.text
        bold: True
        font_style: "Caption"
        opposite_colors: True

MyMDScreenManager:
    MDScreen:
        name: "home_screen"
        MDScrollView:
            MDGridLayout:
                id: _mybox
                cols: 2
                adaptive_height: True
                padding:10
                spacing:10
 
    PictureMDScreen:
        id: _picture_screen
        name: "picture_screen"
        root: root
        photo_preview: _preview
        MDFloatLayout:
            Preview:
                id: _preview
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "camera"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                on_release: 
                    _preview.capture_photo(location = "private", name = _picture_screen.picture_name) # or capture_screenshot()

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "close"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .8, "center_y": .5}
                on_release: _picture_screen.close()
                    
'''

class PictureMDScreen(MDScreen):
    tile = ObjectProperty()
    root = ObjectProperty()
    picture_name = StringProperty()
    photo_preview = ObjectProperty(None) # store the widget instance Preview
    source = StringProperty()
    
    def on_enter(self):
        self.photo_preview.connect_camera(filepath_callback= self.capture_path)
        # self.photo_preview.preview.orientation = 90 # trying to have portrait orientation

    def on_pre_leave(self):
        print("preleaving")
        self.photo_preview.disconnect_camera()
    
    def capture_path(self,file_path): ## called when clicking on the camera button
        if platform == "android":
            source = file_path
            destination = join(app_storage_path(), "app", self.picture_name + ".png")
            self.source = destination

            try:
                os.rename(source,destination) # move a file from source to destination
            except Exception as e:
                log("error : " + str(e))
            time.sleep(1)
            
        elif platform in ["win","macos"]:
            self.source = self.picture_name + ".jpg"

        try:
            self.tile.source = self.source
            self.tile.ids.image.reload() # reload image from cache
        except Exception as e:
            log("error" + str(e))

    def close(self):
        if platform == "android":
                self.photo_preview.disconnect_camera()
        self.root.current = 'home_screen'

    def checkExifOrientation(self,im):
        '''
        Exif is information inscrusted in an image, we can check 
        orientation thanks to im._getexif()["274"]
        just for information : PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[274] gives "Orientation"
        '''
        if im._getexif().get("274"): # check in exif dictionary if 274 in 
            log("has exif in it")
            if im["274"] == 6:
                log("image is portrait")
                return "portrait"
            elif im["274"] == 1:
                log("image is landscape")
                return "landscape"
            else:
                log("we don't know, image is portrait")
                return "portrait"
        else: 
            log("there is no exif 274 so image is portrait")
            return "portrait"
        
    def app_name(self):
        context = mActivity.getApplicationContext()
        appinfo = context.getApplicationInfo()
        if appinfo.labelRes:
            name = context.getString(appinfo.labelRes)
        else:
            name = appinfo.nonLocalizedLabel.toString()
        return name
        
class MyMDSmartTile(MDSmartTile):
    text = StringProperty()

class MyMDScreenManager(MDScreenManager): 

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):

        #Create the tiles
        for i in range(10):
            self.ids._mybox.add_widget(MyMDSmartTile(text = str(i)))

class CameraCuisto(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        self.dont_gc = AndroidPermissions(self.start_app)

    def start_app(self):
        self.dont_gc = None

    def on_start(self, **kwargs):
        if platform == "android":
            from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
            request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.CAMERA])
            log('Perm requested')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CameraCuisto().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to find a satisfying solution : below the link to the solution.
What I want : return current device Orientation at real time even when the orientation set in buildozer is fixed to one orientation like "portrait"

## Final Solution :

A bit complexe, it uses Java and Jnius detailed in my repo created for this : https://github.com/javixav/CameraDeviceOrientation

## Unsuccessfull attempts :

### 1.AndroidPythonActivity

`AndroidPythonActivity.mActivity.getRequestedOrientation()`

> returns the requested Orientation, if buildozer spec orientation is portrait, will return Portrait always.
> We can change the "default orientation" mode by : activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#screenOrientation
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR

### 2.With getResources()

`activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation`

> returns Portrait or Landscape, but not reverse Portrait or reverse Landscape and depends on the "default orientation"

### 3.With width and height :

```
class MyLabel(MDLabel):
    orientation = StringProperty()
    def on_size(self, layout, size):
        if Window.width < Window.height:
            self.orientation = f"portait , size : {str(size)}, Window: {Window.size}"
        else:
            self.orientation = f"landscape , size : {str(size)}, Window: {Window.size}"
```

> returns Portrait or Landscape, but not reverse Portrait or reverse Landscape and depends on the "default orientation"

### 4.With exif :

```
def checkExifOrientation(self,im):
    '''
    im is an image like :
    From PIL import Image
    im = Image.open(destination)
    Exif is information inscrusted in an image, we can check 
    orientation thanks to im._getexif()["274"]
    just for information : PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[274] gives "Orientation"
    if 1 : landscape
    if 6 : portrait
    if 3 : reverse landscape 
    if 8 : reverse portrait
    For this code to be working you need to have all orientations unlock (in buildozer.spec orientation = all
    or you can set it dynamically thanks to activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR)
    '''

    exif = im._getexif()

    if exif.get(274):
        code = exif[274]
        if code == 6:
            orientation = "portrait"
        elif code == 1:
            orientation = "landscape"
        elif code == 3:
            orientation = "landscape-reverse"
        elif code == 8:
            orientation = "portrait-reverse"
        else:
            orientation = "unknown code orientation : " + str(code)
    else:
        orientation = "no exif 274"

    return orientation
```

> works but you need to set RequestedOrientation to fullsensor to have 4 directions, the reason this solution was discarted is because when the user changes orientation, the screen rotates, and it's ugly but I can retrieve the correct device orientation mode.

### 5.With getDefaultDisplay()

`rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()`

> returns [0,1,2,3 etc...] which is the setRequestedOrientation, same result than exif