# IS Android killing kivy when kivy loads too many images?

Tags: python, android, memory, kivy

- kivy: 2.2.1
- kivymd 1.2.0dev0
- python3
- android 10 api 29
- androidstorage4kivy 0.0.0

Hi folks !

#### What I want :

Import a large amont of images (100) from android Documents storage to kivy app, and display them quiet fast (less than 3s)

#### What I've done:

I've succeed to import from shared storage to private app storage thanks to androidstorage4kivy. In the on_start method I create X number of Tiles that loads X jpg images, with X beeing a NumericValue that I can change (I tried to isolate the memory issue so I put a TextField to hold the number of images loaded, so I can test)

#### What I get :

- When loading less than 20 images it is ok,
- between 20 to 30 images I have an slow reloading images process when app is on resume, so each times app is on resume, all images are reloading.
- After 31 images to up, I am facing what I think a memory issue.

When kivy loads the images, too much images, I end up with a black screen, I think android is killing the activity. In logcat I can read things like :

- E InputDispatcher: channel : Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
- Process 7798 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)

### What about the script ?

I can give the full script (240 lines a bit long). Better to give the snippets :

```
class MyMDSmartTile(MDSmartTile):
    index_picture = StringProperty()

    def on_kv_post(self, widget):
        if exists(join("images", self.index_picture + ".jpg")) :
            self.source = join("images", self.index_picture + ".jpg") 
        else:
            self.source = join("images","default.png")

class ErrorBlackScreen(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        # instanciate Tiles : 
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(total): # total is a user input
            self.root.ids.grid.add_widget(MyMDSmartTile(index_picture = str(i+1)))
```

### What I can do ?

What would be your advise to look in before :

- reducing image weight ?
- Test Loader kivy, tweak asynchronous loader :
  https://kivy.org/doc/stable/_modules/kivy/loader.html
  https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.loader.html
- Maybe try different approach not loading image on kv post,
- Dive into atlas features
- Dive into cython performance
- I need help :p

Comment: `Tiles that loads X jpg images,` I have no idea what that would be. Dont you use a ListView or RecycleView to display the whole?

Comment: @blackapps Let says X = 30, I retrieve the 30 images thanks to 30 Tiles in a GridLayout with 2 columns. You can see a picture here  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77049645/camera4kivy-displays-image-in-90-position-when-taking-picture-in-portrait-orie

Comment: GridLayout is a MASSIVE problem.  Use RecyclerView.  The difference is that GridLayout requires an ImageView per cell.  Which means it's storing the entire bitmap in memory uncompressed per cell.  Which is a MASSIVE amount of memory.  You should be using Recycler to avoid having more ImageViews than display on screen, and you should NOT be holding the bitmaps in the model for the cell, only the URL or file its saved as

Comment: This would also be a goog place to consider an LRU cache or image caching library